How to solve this problem combining sequences and reasoning using code?
QUESTION:
Let $m$ be a positive integer, and let $a_1, a_2, ..., a_{4m+2}$ be an arithmetic sequence with non-zero common difference. If removing two terms $a_i$ and $a_j$ ($i < j$) leaves $4m$ terms that can be evenly divided into $m$ groups, and each group of four numbers forms an arithmetic sequence, then call the sequence $a_1, a_2, ..., a_{4m+2}$ a $(i, j)$-divisible sequence.
(I) List all possible pairs $(i, j)$ such that $1 \leq i < j \leq 6$ making the sequence $a_1, a_2, ..., a_6$ a $(i, j)$-divisible sequence.
(II) Prove that when $m \geq 3$, the sequence $a_1, a_2, ..., a_{4m+2}$ is a $(2, 13)$-divisible sequence.
(III) Given any two distinct integers $i$ and $j$ chosen from $1, 2, ..., 4m+2$ with $i < j$, denote by $P_m$ the probability that the sequence $a_1, a_2, ..., a_{4m+2}$ is a $(i, j)$-divisible sequence. Show that $P_m > \frac{1}{8}$.

Objective:
According to each scenario, draw the corresponding charts, similar to the map styles shown in the attached images.
Just like the pictures as follows. Remove two numbers in it and mark them with the same color. For the remaining four numbers in each group that can form an arithmetic sequence, they are also marked with the same color. The colors for the arithmetic sequences in each group are different from each other.


The content below is a rough idea of how to do it by hand.

The first question is easy; just understand the problem:
(1) i, j = (1, 2), (1, 6), (5, 6)

The second question:
Let $\left\{{a}_{m+2}\right\}$ have a common difference $d$. For the second part, we can start with the simplest case where $m=3$ and remove ${a}_{2},{a}_{13}$ from $\left\{{a}_{14}\right\}$:
[ {a}{1},{a}{3},{a}{4},{a}{5},{a}{6},{a}{7},{a}{8},{a}{9},{a}{10},{a}{11},{a}{12},{a}{14} ]
We try to construct three arithmetic sequences each with four terms. Let's consider the sequence $\left\{{a}_{1},{a}_{{i}_{1}},{a}_{{i}_{2}},{a}_{{i}_{3}}\right\}$ where $i_i\geqslant 3$. The common difference of this sequence should be at least $2d$.
If $d_0=2d,i_1=3,i_2=5,i_3=7$, we will find that the remaining eight terms cannot form two more arithmetic sequences, so let's try $d_0=3d$. It is easy to arrange:$\left\{{a}_{1},{a}_{4},{a}_{7},{a}_{10}\right\}$ $\left\{{a}_{3},{a}_{6},{a}_{9},{a}_{12}\right\}$ $\left\{{a}_{5},{a}_{8},{a}_{11},{a}_{14}\right\}$
For $m\geqslant 4$, as long as we first arrange these three arithmetic sequences, then divide ${a}_{15},{a}_{16},\cdots ,{a}_{4m+2}$ into $\left\{{a}_{{4k}+3},{a}_{{4k}+4},{a}_{{4k}+5},{a}_{{4k}+6}\right\}$ for $3\leqslant k\leqslant m-1$, we're done.

(3) This question is asking about what conditions on $i$ and $j$ make it possible to split $\left\{{a}_{4m+2}\right\}$ into $(i,j)$.
Firstly, let's count the total number of possibilities for $(i,j)$: $C_{4m+2}^2=\frac{(4m+2)(4m+1)}{2}=8m^2+6m+1$
Similarly, we start with the simplest situation where all the resulting sequences have equal differences, which means after removing ${a}_{i},{a}_{j}$ from $\left\{{a}_{4m+2}\right\}$, the remaining elements can be divided into $m$ groups such that each group has four consecutive numbers.
What conditions do $i$ and $j$ need to satisfy? Clearly, $i=1,j=2$ works. We remove ${a}_{1}$ first, then ${a}_{2}$. Then $\left\{{a}_{3},{a}_{4},...,{a}_{4m+2}\right\}$ can be divided into $\left\{{a}_{{4k}+3},{a}_{{4k}+4},{a}_{{4k}+5},{a}_{{4k}+6}\right\}(0\leqslant k\leqslant m-1)$ in order to meet the requirements. Since the sequences are always composed of four elements, both $i=4p+1$ and $j=4q+2$ ($0\leqslant p\leqslant q\leqslant m$) work. How many ways are there to choose $p$ and $q$?
When $p=0$, $q$ has $m+1$ choices. When $p=1$, $q$ has $m$ choices. ... When $p=m$, $q$ has $1$ choice. So there are $\frac{(m+1)(m+2)}{2}$ ways in total. However, compared to $8m^2+6m+1$, the probability is only greater than $\frac{1}{16}$ but not $\frac{1}{8}$. Therefore, we need to look for other situations.
Note that the premise of question (2) is not in the form of $i = 4p + 1, j = 4q + 2$ $(0 \le p \le q \le m)$, but rather in the form of $i = 4p + 2, j = 4q + 1$ $(0 \le p < q \le m)$.
We also need to note that this form is not always feasible. For example, $j = i + 3$ does not work. Let $m = 1$, then $(i, j) = (2, 5)$, and it's impossible for $a_1, a_3, a_4, a_6$ to be an arithmetic sequence.
What about $j = i + 7$? Let $m = 2$, then $(i, j) = (2, 9)$,
$a_1, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7, a_8, a_{10}$ can be divided into $\{a_1, a_3, a_5, a_7\}$ and $\{a_2, a_4, a_6, a_8\}$
When $j = i + 11$, we can construct according to the method in question (2), as long as $(i, j) = (2, 4m + 1)$, we can construct $m$ arithmetic sequences with common difference $m$. At this point, we find that except for $j = i + 3$, other forms of $i = 4p + 2, j = 4q + 1$ $(0 \le p < q \le m)$ are possible. The probability here is actually enough.


I understand the problem that you want to solve. Then what  do you want from Stack Exchange?

@A.Kato
How to use visual charts to demonstrate these three issues?

You have your own secret answer already :-)

@A.Kato  Nothing is a secret answer.Nor has any secret answer been obtained.
